# find and replace a specific string of a a particular line in txt file with php

Tags: php, html, text, web, replace

I want to know that how can I replace a specific word/string of a particular line into a text file with php.

Contents of text file is as below:

```
 1|1|1
 nikki|nikki@yahoo.com|nikki
 nikki|nikki@gmail.com|nikki
 nikki|nikki@hotmail.com|nikki
```

DETAILS OF FIELDS:

```
 COLUMN:0 = $name,
 COLUMN:1 = $email,
 COLUMN:2 = $nickname,
```

DETAILS OF REPLACEMENT:

```
 COLUMN:0 = $newName,
 COLUMN:1 = $newEmail,
 COLUMN:2 = $newnickName,
```

From the above content you can guess that the find/search is based on the column:1. Ans if match found, than replace the column:0 OR column:2 [based on the choice].

I tried [for finding the column:1]:

```
 $fileData = file("file.txt");
 foreach($fileData as $Key => $Val) { 
  $Data[$Key] = explode("|", $Val);
  if ( trim($Data[$Key][1]) == $email ){
unset($fileData[$Key]);
    //REPLACE TAKE PLACE HERE
    break;
  }
 }
```

[for replace]:

```
 /* REPLACE NAME */
 $file = "file.txt";
 $oname = "|$name|";$nname = "|$newName|";
 file_put_contents($file, str_replace($oname, $nname, file_get_contents($file)));
 /* REPLACE NICKNAME */
 $file = "file.txt";
 $onickname = "|$nickname|";$nnickname = "|$newnickname|";
 file_put_contents($file, str_replace($onickname, $nnickname, file_get_contents($file)));
```

But it was replacing all the matching "$name".

I also tried in the following way:

```
 $fileData[$Key] = str_replace($name, $newName, $fileData[$Key]);
 file_put_contents($file,$fileData);

/* $name & $newName -:> $nickname & $newnickname
```

But it doesn't works.

If i want to replace column:0 ["nikki"] of "nikki@gmail.com" with "nikkigmail", then the data should be:

```
 1|1|1
 nikki|nikki@yahoo.com|nikki
 nikkigmail|nikki@gmail.com|nikki
 nikki|nikki@hotmail.com|nikki
```

And, if want to replace column:2 ["nikki"] of "nikki@hotmail.com" with "hotmail", then:

```
 1|1|1
 nikki|nikki@yahoo.com|nikki
 nikkigmail|nikki@gmail.com|nikki
 nikki|nikki@hotmail.com|hotmail
```

May i get the code to be corrected ?

Comment: Can you post your expected output ?

Comment: @Shankar : thanks for replying.
I already posted the expected code.

REPLACE CODE 1 works good, but this replace all the matching $name in the text file, not just column:0 OR column:2.

I want to only replace the column:0 OR column:2 strings, BASED on the column:1

Comment: I didn't ask about the code.. I meant how you want the final output of the text file to be. (after replacements)

Comment: have you tried this steps? 1: open file in read mode. 2. Replace contents on desired place. 3. then opening file as write mode. 4. then do writing the replaced contents.

Comment: LIKE: 
if I want to replace column:1 of "nikki@gmail.com" with "nikkigmail", then
     nikki|nikki@yahoo.com|nikki <br/>
     nikkigmail|nikki@gmail.com|nikki <br/>
     nikki|nikki@hotmail.com|nikki <br/>

Comment: @moyeen: yeh, I tried this. but it also replace all the matching words.

Comment: Why just `nikkigmail` ? Shouldn't be `nikkiyahoo` and `nikkihotmail` in the 1st and 3rd line ?

Comment: @shankar: it can be anything.

actually replacement word is based on the users input and replacement strictly based on the column:1.

Comment: @NikitaChaudhary, Still very unclear because.. I see it is getting replaced on first column and sometimes it is doing the replacement on the third column. Does this have any rules of replacement ?

Comment: @shankar : question updated. 
column:0 = $name, column:1 = $email, column:2 = $nickname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would replace something like this. Instead of worrying about str_replace, why not actually modify the array returned by `file`?

```
<?php

$email = "nikki@gmail.com"; // Search email
$data = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // Read in the data

foreach($data as $key => $line) {
    $bits = explode("|", $line);
    if($bits[1] === $email) {
        // Update this in place,
        $bits[0] = "nikkigmail";
        $data[$key] = implode("|", $bits);
    }
}

$write = implode("\n", $data); // the data to write however you please.
```

Keep in mind this can also be expanded to suit your row/column needs. For example, you could use something like this.

```
/**
 * The reason these are named differently is because they don't always
 * search/replace. For example, you can find nikki@gmail.com in one row,
 * but just be setting a different column in that row to a value..
 */

$match = array('col' => 1, 'str' => 'nikki@gmail.com'); // Search data at row
$update = array('col' => 0, 'str' => 'nikkigmail'); // Replace data at row

$data = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // Read in the data

foreach($data as $key => $line) {
    $bits = explode("|", $line);
    if($bits[$match['col']] === $match['str']) {
        // Update this in place,
        $bits[$update['col']] = $update['str'];
        $data[$key] = implode("|", $bits);
    }
}

$write = implode("\n", $data); // the data to write however you please.
```

Comment: This is exactly the way to do it. The OP's question is not using any form of search and replace; it is implicitly treating the data as a 2D array (where lines in the file are rows and pipes create columns).

Comment: @Tristan : hmmm... lukin nice piece of code :) let me try this

Comment: Keep in mind I haven't actually tested this on data, you might have to fiddle with it, if you have any problems let me know and I can take a look.

Comment: It doesn't actually *write* any data by the way, I left that part for you to do. The variable `$write` at the end contains ALL of the files text contents you need to write.

Comment: I used "$fp = fopen("text.txt", "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!_success");
 fwrite($fp,implode("\n", $data)) or die("Couldn't write values to file!_success"); 
 fclose($data);" in the place of "$write". And this code just make a copy of the file content and add them at the end on the file in a single line

and when use "w" [write], then just make a copy of file and replace it with the content into a single line

Comment: are you using "\n" when you implode?

Comment: @tristan: no replacement take place with this code :(

Comment: ... Let me test it myself then. One minute.

Comment: Yep, it replaced it perfectly fine for me when I used, `file_put_contents('file.txt', implode("\n", $data));` to write the data. If that doesn't work, you could try using `PHP_EOL` in place of `"\n"`. Also, notepad isn't going to show you new lines properly. (sidenote)

Comment: @tristan: "file_put_contents" works perfectly, but why "PHP_EOL" add a blank line after every lines?

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is the platform specific end of line character. Some people run into problems using just `"\n"` so prefer to use the constant `PHP_EOL` instead. I've always used `\n` and never had any problems though. Goodluck with your work!

Comment: the `col` number in `$match` determines which column you are searching for `str` in, the `col` number in `$replace` determines which `col` you want to set to `$replace`'s `str`.

Comment: @tristan: yup, I can understood this. but col:0 is cleared before/after replacing col:2. Tried: "$match = array('col' => 1, 'str' => 'hotmail');
 $update = array('col' => 2, 'str' => 'tiger');
 $data = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
 foreach($data as $key => $line) {
      $bits = explode("|", $line);
      if($bits[$match['col']] === $match['str']) {
        $bits[$update['col']] = $update['str'];
        $data[$key] = implode("|", $bits);
      }
 }
 file_put_contents('file.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $data));"

Comment: That will match the row where column one is "hotmail" and then it will put "tiger" in column two of that same row.

Comment: @tristan: yeh, but while I'm trying to replace column:2 value, than it also erase the value of column:0.
before replacing column:2 = "nikki|nikki@gmail.com|hotmail", after replacement = "|nikki@gmail.com|tiger".

Please help me :(